# Design Pattern with Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, design-patterns

i'm creating a website in PHP, that has Javascript elements as well. This one, will be having what is like a plugin system where a plugin can be dynamically added to the website.

I've created the plugin system, but i don't like certain elements of the design. In particular, i'm using an MVC pattern, but there is a problem with javascript abstraction.

I have a certain file that loads all the plugins. Then, there is a javascript file that dynamically adds boxes to a window, depending on the selection that was made, for what plugin should be used.

It goes like this in a js file :

```
 if (SelValue == 'image_list')
   image_list(form_name, new_div, parent_div);

 if (SelValue == 'multiple_columns')
   multiple_columns(form_name, new_div, parent_div);
```

Then, right below, follows the declaration of imagelist() and so on. Of course, this is pretty cumbersome and certainly does not look like a good practice. I would like to have all of these abstracted and isolated, so that a plugin is just a simple step to add to my code, if possible.

Do you know of any design pattern or practice that could fit this scenario ?

Comment: Something you might find usefull : https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Object holding all functions like `image_list` and `multiple_columns`. Using those would look like:

```
plugins[SelValue](form_name, new_div, parent_div);
```

Adding a new function would look like this:

```
plugins.image_list = function (form_name, new_div, parent_div) {
    /* … */
}
```

This definition could go in a different file. Is that what you meant?

**Edit:** Pretty single-file version:

```
plugins = {
    image_list: function (form_name, new_div, parent_div) {
        /* … */
    },
    multiple_columns: function (form_name, new_div, parent_div) {
        /* … */
    },
};
plugins[SelValue](form_name, new_div, parent_div);
```

Comment: Well, i'm actually quite hesitant about using multiple js files, because of performance purposes. With that in mind, i would like to make it follow a design pattern style, like the open/closed principle or programming on interfaces. I was thinking about it close to your solution, but since this is js and not c++, multiple files can be a problem.

Comment: Well, you don’t have to put it in different files. Just use a hash/object to DRY away the if / switch.

Comment: It's certainly a prettier version than the one i have now. Well, it seems that javascript and too much oop is not in accordance anyway, so this could indeed be the most preferable solution. Since i do have to put the declarations in one file, it will be kinda bloated anyway :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to have more than 2 IF statements, that would be sufficient. However, if you're going to be extending it (or could foresee it expanding), then I would suggest using a Factory/Command design pattern. Implementation details would include a table or a dictionary to replace the multiple IF-statements that you would have.

Comment: yes, it's actually like 15 IFs already ;) I am looking at that pattern now.

Answer (score 1):

The module pattern would probably fit your needs very well. This pattern basically would treat each "plugin" as a module, which itself should be fully functional and independent. Then you have a module loader/controller, which is responsible for loading the correct modules, and enabling modules to communicate with each other.

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Comment: that is interesting, i'm taking a closer look thanx